# output file to another directory

Tags: python, bash, file-io

I have a python script and I wrote it such that it will generate an output file to a new directory called `test` using these two lines:

```
self.mkdir_p("test") # create directory named "test"
file_out = open("test/"+input,"w")
```

and the mkdir_p function is as follow:

```
def mkdir_p(self,path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as exc:
        if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST:
            pass
        else: raise
```

Now, I have all the files that I would like my script to run on stored in directory called `storage`, and my question is, how can I write a script such that I can run all the files in `storage` from my home directory(where my python script is located), and saved all the output to the `test` directory as I coded in my python script?

I did a naive approach in bash like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the directory name where the files are stored (storage)
in=$1

# for files in (storage) directory
for f in $1/*

do

  echo "Processing $f file..."
  ./my_python_script.py $f

done
```

and it didnt work and threw IOError: `No such file or directory: 'test/storage/inputfile.txt'`

I hope I explained my problem clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to encode either a local path or a global path to `test`. I'd recommend going with the global path. So `/home/user/.../test/`

Comment: By the by, you should double-quote `"$f"`. It's probably harmless here, but you should build a habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$f` is `storage/inputfile.txt` and Python prepends `test/` to that, then complains because `test/storage` does not exist. Create the directory, or strip the directory part before creating the output file name.

Comment: so now I have removed the directory creation part, which is the ``self.mkdir_p("test")`` line, and have the directory created before I run the script but it still gives me the same problem..

Comment: Huh? You need to trim the `storage/` part, wirh something like `basename = input.split('/')[-1]`